# Issues with performance while porting from async model to multiprocessing model in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, multiprocessing

This problem seems like impossible to solve, so I'd really like some help.
I'm using python 3.7, but can upgrade to 3.11 if absolutely necessary.

## The original problem

A series of tasks has to be performed. These tasks can be complex and take up to 5 minutes to complete execution. But they're **mostly I/O bound**. The number of tasks to be performed can vary from 1-100,000. There can be 1-50 tasks being executed at the same time. The time that takes to execute a single task is all that matters in terms of performance.
Each task has four types of outputs. Let's call them A, B, C and D. A and B can have size ranging from a few bytes up to 5 MB and each task could output 0-10,000 of each of them. C and D will be 1-5 KB in size and each task will assuredly output 10 of them each. These are to be output into 4 different queues.

## Current solution - async model

Currently, each task is scheduled as a separate async task by a main process. Since everything runs in a single process, outputs can be easily shared to the main process from each async task. Everything just works.

## Issue with the async model

There can be some sync blocking code in the task that is to be executed. This causes all the tasks to stop executing for that time. Furthermore, the task could hang infinitely (I have minimum control over what the task is), stopping the execution of all other tasks completely.

## Solution to the issue - multiprocessing

The solution was to run the tasks in separate processes. The outputs were shared to the main process via a multiprocessing queue, while using a semaphore to control the speed so that memory could be conserved. The semaphore was only used for outputs A and B, since the other outputs would always be smaller in size. I went about this in two approaches.

First approach was to spawn a process to run each task. But this incurred a large overhead in creating processes and caused significant performance deterioration in cases where the number of tasks were high and the number of outputs were low.

Second approach was to get a few processes up and running to execute the tasks. The main process would use a shared queue to share data regarding the task to be executed to each of these processes.

I used multiprocessing.Process to create processes in both approaches. All the shared queues were created using a multiprocessing.Manager.

## Problems I'm facing now

Multiprocessing model is **considerably slower** than the async model, given the same processing power. A particular task which yields 20,000 of B outputs completes execution in 2 minutes in async model while it takes around 5 minutes in multiprocessing model. I have to keep the processing power the same. A minimal increase is acceptable as well.

The difference in performance is understandable, since tasks are mostly I/O bound, which is more suited to an async model. The pickling and unpickling while using the shared queue adds to the overhead in the multiprocessing model.

I need to speed up the multiprocessing model to give at least the **same or slightly reduced** performance as the async model.

I have tried using different multiprocessing.Manager for each queue, and I've tried using the same multiprocessing.Manager for all queues. I have tried using a local redis server to share the data instead of a shared queue. Nothing seems to increase the performance.

I'd really appreciate any solutions to either the problem in async model or suggestions to speed up the multiprocessing model.

Comment: If tasks are **mostly I/O bound**, maybe you should use `threading` or `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of `multiprocessing`. You seem to have tried a lot of things but you don't show us anything.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting something like this. This problem has been in the pipeline to be solved for a while now. I think we had tried threading, but there was some other issues with it. Nevertheless, I'll give it a try again. As for examples, the code base is a little complex and intertwined, so I'll look if I can make a simpler example out of it.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)